# Link in HTML e-mail does not work in Hotmail

Tags: asp.net, smtp, dns, spf, dkim

I send automated mails to hotmail users. (thank you for your registration bla bla)
Because plain text doesn't look attractive enough, I use HTML with images. The images reside on a public webserver.

As SMTP server I use the SMTP part of IIS 7.5 (windows 2008 R2). I have an SPF record setup in the DNS. I have also read http://tinisles.blogspot.com/2009/09/sending-dkim-email-from-c.html and found out that sending mail with the SMTP service and a DKIM signature cannot be done properly without an external commercial component. So I do not have such thing (yet).

Now that is all about my background and here is the problem:
I have this in my HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com">click here</a>
```

But when users get am e-mail like that and view it in hotmail. (chrome, IE, safari etc.) and when they hover the link they will see that the url is `http://www.mydomain.com` but when they click on it. It redirects to:

`http://www.mydomain.com/mail/InboxLight.aspx/404.aspx?msg=The%20file%20'/mail/InboxLight.aspx'%20does%20not%20exist`

what am I doing wrong? Is it an SMTP/IIS server setting? Did I forget something in my Asp.Net C# code when I have send the mail? Did I forget something in the DNS or HTML markup?

The link works perfectly when I receive the mail in my Outlook 2010 where the domain is also added to the safelist.

**EDIT** If it seems to be all related to the antispam stuff in hotmail. Should I consider to buy: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98oc_5bjjkc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because the text displayed in the link ("click here") does not tell the user where they are going when they click. Take a look at the [hotmail postmaster](http://mail.live.com/mail/postmaster.aspx) site for more info, in particular, the troubleshooting page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ray. But it's not just `click here` that's shown. It's a full sentence. Click here to login to our site. But that isn't listed on that website as reason to block the working url.

Comment: On the troubleshooting page, look at "Why does the e-mail that I send to Windows Live Hotmail users sometimes look different from what they receive?" Since your <a> tag only contains "click here", I thought maybe this was the problem. They can probably only analyze the text within the tag itself, not the context in which it appears.

Comment: Ok, so I should change it to: go to <a href..>www.mydomain.com</a> to login to our site

Comment: That's how I read it - but who know what Hotmail will actually do... :)

Comment: K, will give it a try and update this thread a.s.a.p. thanks for your time and effort